# How to offset or loft surface maintaining cross-sectional area?

Tags: modeling, scripting

I have this surface (blue) which I would like "offset" inwards (yellow) while maintaining the same cross-sectional area (red). Loft is probably the correct method, since the cross-sections can be defined. Is it possible to create a script for this in Blender?

[image: offset by surface area]